# ProgressDialog working in thread on android

Tags: java, android

I have a little problem, I hope U can help me;)

Trouble is, that ProgressDialog show only after loading run(), but I need to show it on start and showing it while loading some data. I put: "dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CategoriesListActivity.this,"Working...","Loading data", true);" in method run(), but the same. I print in Log.i() some info (int i++) and put title of ProgressDialog. Method work correctly, but don't show ProgressDialog. I have read some info that some thread block another thread (my created), that's why doesn't show progressDialog, but can't do anything. Thx.

```
    public void run() {

        /** getting there long execution **/
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // stop and hide dialog
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(CategoriesListActivity.this, "Working...",
                "Loading data", true);

        // start new thread where get long time execution
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        //wait while data is loading, 'cause I need use variable from calculation
                // in "EfficientAdapter" later
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's done with the help of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (an intelligent backround thread) and [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

When the AsyncTask starts we raise a progressdialog with indeterminate state, once the task is finished we dismiss the dialog.

**Example code**
What the adapter does in this example is not important, more important to understand that you need to use AsyncTask to display a dialog for the progress.

```
private class PrepareAdapter1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ContactsListCursorAdapter > {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewContacts.this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait_while_loading));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
     */
    @Override
    protected ContactsListCursorAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
        cur1 = objItem.getContacts();
        startManagingCursor(cur1);

        adapter1 = new ContactsListCursorAdapter (viewContacts.this,
                R.layout.contact_for_listitem, cur1, new String[] {}, new int[] {});

        return adapter1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ContactsListCursorAdapter result) {
        list.setAdapter(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```