# ProgressDialog won't display - multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progressdialog

I am trying to start a ProgressDialog in the main thread but it won't show at all. The flow is such that I start ProgressDialog in main thread and then start a thread where some actions are performed. After the actions are complete ProgressDialog  is dismissed.

My code is as:

**Main class:**

```
final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(someclass.this, "Please wait ...",    "Configuring...", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        spinnerThread t = new spinnerThread(this, ringProgressDialog);
        t.start(); //Dialog won't show
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent i = new Intent("org.CameraDemo"); //Activity won't start and the app itself closes
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
        finish();
```

**Thread class:**

```
class spinnerThread extends Thread {
    ProgressDialog progress;
    someclass someobject;

    public spinnerThread(someclass someobject,
            ProgressDialog progress) {
        super();
        this.someobject= someobject;
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        someobject.action1();
        someobject.action2();
        someobject.action3();
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Requesting downvoters to atleast mention the reason. As without reason one can't know whats missing in the question.**

Comment: You need to call show() on your ProgressDialog.

Comment: @AdityaGupta show() is already called when progress dialog is initialized.

Comment: join() will block the main UI thread until spinnerThread finishes its job. So the main thread doesn't get a chance to show the dialog as it first waits for spinnerthread to finish,but spinnerthread calls dismiss() on the dialog at its end. So why did you use join()?

Comment: @Luksprog Seems you got it what I was missing! You can see after the thread execution is over I want to switch to another activity. If I don't block it the main activity will switch over to next activity without completing the task. Which is what I dont want.                          I want the thread to complete first then resume to the main thread from the same place. Does it make sense?

Comment: Well, that's not how you do it. Instead of a Thread use an AsyncTask passing it the activity reference, do the work in doInBackground() and start the activity in onPostExecute(). The AsyncTask also has the onPreExecute() callback where you may want to initialize the ProgressDialog and show it(which you'll later dismiss in the same onPostExecute() method).

Comment: @Luksprog Okay! I was not aware of this approach. I shall check it. I guess your approach is somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343490/progressdialog-working-in-thread-on-android. Please post your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `join()` on the spinnerthread that you create and start, this will block the UI thread until spinnerthread finishes its job. The dialog doesn't appear because, although you create and initialize it correctly in the activity, you dismiss it in the spinnerthread on which the main UI thread waits before doing anything else(like actually showing the dialog).

If you're trying to do some non trivial work(which could potentially cause an ANR) before starting the new activity I would recommend using an `AsyncTask` as it's more feature rich than a simple thread. You would initialize and show the `ProgressDialog` in the `onPreExecute()` callback, do the work in the `doInBackground()` callback followed by dismissing the dialog and starting the new activity in the `onPostExecute()` callback.

You can still use a normal thread but you'll need to remove the `join()` call followed by starting the new activity at the end of thespinnerthread's `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void showCancelableProgressDialog(String title, String message, int pbarstyle, String cancelLabel, OnClickListener cancelListener) {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.setMessage(message);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);  //if you are not showing proper progress
    dialog.setProgressStyle(pbarstyle); //the style you want like horizontal progress bar or spinner type
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, cancelLabel, cancelListener);

    dialog.show();
}
```

while calling this menthod you can do like this

```
        Thread th = new Thread(){                   
                        @Override
                        public void run (){
                            showCancelableProgressDialog(your title, your message, ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                         
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 // handle what your cancel button needs to do

                                  }
                          });
                 }


       }
        th.start();
```

check out with this one....

Comment: I am afraid the above Async example would suit best for this situation. Thread creation won't help much.

Comment: @Raj..... If you have to start the progress dialog for a AsycTask then you can start in onPreExecute() and then stop the progress dialog in onPostExecute()....And also if you will see the implementation of AsycTask then you can find that it has thread pool so it is starting the task on different thread not on main thread so why you want to add another thread to that....anyway sorry for delay because you already accepted the answer :)